Not able to get authentication token in JMeter
My current application login flow is as mentioned below:

Access application URL
Application redirects to Microsoftonline
Insert username >> click Next
Insert password >> click SignIn
Click on Yes on Stay signed in? dialog box.
Browser shows token as part of response header with status code 302.
Status code 302 in browser dev tool

However in JMeter I am getting 200 OK response and unable to see access token in header response.
Note that I have done correlation for input parameters. Moreover I am able to get access token using postman.
[Jmeter sampler result] (https://i.sstatic.net/2fJ2eY7M.png)
Jmeter response header
Followed below mentioned approaches but those didn't worked.

Check/uncheck of "Follow Redirects" option.
Check/uncheck of "Redirect Automatically" option.
Used other approach as suggested in article here: https://www.vanderveer.io/jmeter-azure-ad-no-plugins/. I am able to get the token but it failed to perform user access level functionality.


I am able to resolve the access token issue by following below article.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth-ropc

If you're not seeing the token it means that the request you're sending is not the same as your browser sends.
Most probably it's due to missing or incorrectly implemented correlation.
Use a 3rd-party sniffer tool to compare requests from JMeter and from the real browser, the requests must be exactly the same (apart from dynamic parameters which need to be correlated)
Once you send the same request (in fact sequence of requests) your login should succeed.
You can check out https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/oauth2-correlation/src/master/atlassian-microsoft-oauth.jmx example script for reference.

Unfortunately, this didn't worked. I tried several times.

I am able to get 302 response in JMeter after many round of troubleshoot. However I can't see access token in response header. Do you know any option to retrieve token?
